# Using Talend tSystem to run powershell command

Tags: java, talend

I need to upload a file to a site. I am using Talend tSystem component to do the same. I need to run via PowerShell. The statement errors out with escape

Below is the command that I am using. Escape character error occurs
Please suggest where am I going wrong?

```
 "cmd /c start powershell -noninteractive C:\\Curl_windows\\src\\curl.exe -H 'X-API-TOKEN:ZLQuFZWY5zekZd' -F 'surveyId=SV_8dpoD2nJ3' -F 'file=@C:\\Logs\\surveyresponseimport.csv;type=text/csv' 'https:\/\/xxx.com\/API\/v3\/responseimports'"
```

Comment: Try escaping backslashes : every \ becomes \\

Comment: Are you still getting an error after escaping backslashes ? If so, could you update your question with the error ?
Any reason you're not using tFileFetch to upload your file ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Java Exception in this part of your string :

```
'https:\/\/xxx.com\/API\/v3\/responseimports'
```

You haven't escaped the backslashes. Forward slash `/` is not an escapable character in Java, so writing `\/` in your string is throwing an Exception. The updated Java String should look like this:

```
"cmd /c start powershell -noninteractive C:\\Curl_windows\\src\\curl.exe -H 'X-API-TOKEN:ZLQuFZWY5zekZd' -F 'surveyId=SV_8dpoD2nJ3' -F 'file=@C:\\Logs\\surveyresponseimport.csv;type=text/csv' 'https:\\/\\/xxx.com\\/API\\/v3\\/responseimports'"
```

Although I'm not sure why you have written the string like that. Powershell doesn't require you to escape slashes, and Java needs escaping of only backslashes `\`. You can just try removing all the backslashes from that part of the string and check if that alone is sufficient.

Comment: Great.
If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.